# How to compare device max- width and max-hight in cc?

Tags: css

Eg. 
If( device max- width< device max - height)
{
    Apply X property of css
}
Else
{
     Apply y property of css
}

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way in which to approach the problem in css. Look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
An example would be

```css
p {
  font-size: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 767px) {
 p {
   font-size: 3em;
 }
}
```

This would cause the `font-size` property of all `p` tags to be `3em` rather than `1em` when the width of the viewport exceeds `767px`.